# pandasのpd.io.sql.read_sqlでのエラーについて

Tags: python, python3, pandas, postgresql

プログラム初心者です。
下記のコードを実行したところWHEREのところでエラーが出てしまって困っております。
nameで入れたい型はcharacter(16)になっております。
よろしくお願い致します。

エラー内容：

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) 演算子が存在しません: character = bigint
LINE 1: select * from test2 WHERE test_code = 123456789101234
                                                      ^
HINT:  指定名称、指定引数型に合う演算子がありません。明示的な型キャストが必要かもしれません
 [SQL: 'select * from test2 WHERE test_code = 123456789101234'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

コード：

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative
import pandas as pd

url = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:*****@127.0.0.1:****/test'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url)

table_name ='test2'
name = '123456789101234'
query = 'select * from {} WHERE test_code = {}'.format(table_name, name)
df = pd.io.sql.read_sql(query, engine)
print('#############')
print(df)
```

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。query = "select * from {} WHERE 'test_code' = '{}'".format(table_name, name)としたところエラーなくなりました。ただtable_name ='test'
name = '123456789101234'
query = 'select * from {}'.format(table_name)
df2 = pd.io.sql.read_sql(query, engine)
print('#############')
df2 = df2[df2['test_code'] == name]と同様の結果を出したいのですが出ませんでした。ご指摘頂けますと幸いですm(_ _)m

Comment: 元々の問題は解決したようですので、新しい問題は新しく投稿した方がもっといろんな方の目に留まって良いかと思います。コードも見やすくなりますし。新しい質問の方、もう少し詳しく新しい投稿の方に説明して頂いてもよろしいですか？

Comment: 了解致しました。ありがとうございます。問題が解決した場合なにかすることありますでしょうか？投稿が初めてのため不慣れですみません。

Comment: 回答の方、承認済みのボタンを押して頂けますと、この問題は解決したものとして表示されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_code`は文字列ですか？
それとも数字ですか？
もし文字列でしたら`test_code`の部分を`' '`で囲んでみてください。そうすることによって、数字ではなく文字列として扱われます。